# Java program deleting directories with a JButton

Tags: java, swing, file-io, actionlistener, delete-file

I got my program to delete files within a specified file, but then I decided for it to delete the entire directory! This is my code so far, it does nothing when pressing the button... (and the button does have an ActionListener on it).

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource().equals(a)) {
        int ans = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You're about to premenently delete this account! Are you sure you want to continue?", "Caution!!",  JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (ans == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            //delete
            File directory = new File("FileIO Plug-Ins\\Accounts\\" + user);
            deleteDirectory(directory);
        }
        run();
    }
}

public boolean deleteDirectory(File directory) {
    if(directory.exists()){
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if(files != null){
            for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                    deleteDirectory(files[i]);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("deleting: " + files[i].getName());
                    files[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return(directory.delete());
}
```

the for loop I made does indeed find all the files in the specified folder, and the line

```
System.out.println("deleting: " + files[i].getName());
```

does also print every file within the 'user' directory, but doesn't delete them. nor does it delete the folder itself.
Please help! any advise or code source would be great!

Comment: are you getting any exceptions? You may not be having the proper rights to delete it!

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29: you're ignoring the result of File.delete(), which tells if the file has been deleted or not. And as the javadoc suggests, you should prefer Files.delete() which will throw an exception with a halpful message that tells you why the delete didn't succeed.

Comment: make sure you have the access-right from your Operation System to edit this path.

Answer (score 1):

`delete()` returns `boolean` value which *you are ignoring*.

`true` - if and only if file or directory was successfully deleted

`false` - if could not be deleted for **some reason**

To get the reason, use [Files#delete(Path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete%28java.nio.file.Path%29) for deleting the directory, as it gives you exception if the file cannot be deleted due to some reason.

Quoting the JavaDoc for [File#delete()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29)

> Note that the Files class defines the delete method to throw an
>   IOException when a file cannot be deleted. This is useful for error
>   reporting and to diagnose why a file cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in my machine,it's work well.Maybe you don't have permission to delete your target directory.You can test with my code to find out which file's delete operation is failed.

```
public static boolean deleteDirectory(File directory) {
    if(directory.exists()){
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if(files != null){
            for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                    deleteDirectory(files[i]);
                }
                else {
                    if(files[i].delete()) {
                        System.out.println("Successfully delete: " + files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Failed to delete: " + files[i].getAbsolutePath());                          
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(directory.delete()){
         System.out.println("Successfully delete: " + directory.getAbsolutePath());
         return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to delete: " + directory.getAbsolutePath());                         
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So yeah i tested that out with my code, it ends up saying everything has failed.. is that an administrator problem? because I'm the only user on the computer. Or is the file a read only or something?
`Failed to delete: G:\...\FileIO Plug-Ins\Accounts\test\game.ini`

`Failed to delete: G:\...\FileIO Plug-Ins\Accounts\test\test.accounts`

`Failed to delete: G:\...\FileIO Plug-Ins\Accounts\test`

any suggestions?

Comment: I just deleted a read only file in my Windows 7.Can you try to delete this directory manually?Maybe these files are occupied by other process.If so Windows will prompt a warning.